# Accessing and maintaining a fixed array of Collections within a Model

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to understand how to handle number of collection instances within my Backbone model. There will be a primary model and that model is composed of multiple instances of collections. The collections themselves are groups of some other model.

- Model A

  - Collection B

    - Model C
    - Model C
  - Collection B

    - Model C
    - Model C
    - Model C
  - Collection B

    - Model C
  - Collection B

    - `might even be empty but will only add more Model C's`

Here is the Non-working code...

## app.js

```
(function() {
  var App = {};
  window.App = App;

  var template = function(name) {
    return Mustache.compile($('#'+name+'-template').html());
  };

  App.World = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      var this.continent = new Array(); 
      this.continent[0] = new App.Continent(0);
      this.continent[1] = new App.Continent(1);
      this.continent[2] = new App.Continent(2);
      this.continent[3] = new App.Continent(3);
      this.continent[4] = new App.Continent(4);
      this.continent[5] = new App.Continent(5);
    }
  });

  App.Continent = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(id) {
      switch (id) {
        case 0:
          this.id = "Europe";
        case 1:
          this.id = "Asia";
        case 2:
          this.id = "Africa";
        case 3:
          this.id = "Australia";
        case 4:
          this.id = "South America";
        default:
          this.id = "North America";
      }
    }
  });

  App.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: template('index'),
    initialize: function() {
      this.world = new App.World();
      this.world.on('all', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this));
      return this;
    },
    bigland: function() {
      return this.world;
    },
  });

  App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.el = options.el
    },
    routes: {
      "": "index"
    },
    index: function() {
      var index = new App.Index();
      this.el.empty();
      this.el.append(index.render().el);
    }
  });

  App.boot = function(container) {
    container = $(container);
    var router = new App.Router({el: container})
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
})()
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div id='app'>
    Loading...
  </div>

    <script type="text/x-mustache-template" id="index-template">

      <ul>
        {{#bigland}}
        <li>Hello {{.continent}}</li>
        {{/bigland}}
      </ul>

    </script>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>    
    <script>$(function() { App.boot($('#app')); });</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## the output I am trying to get from this demo

- Hello Europe
- Hello Asia
- Hello Africa
- Hello Australia
- Hello South America
- Hello North America

## Questions:

1. How do I get this code to work using the model with multiple instances of collections.
2. Is there a better way structure this model? I am open to using backbone plugins for nested models but like to see some working code.
3. The next level of experimentation is to enable some instances of Collection B to specialize and utilize different business rules. Any thoughts on how to organize this mess like where to put helper methods? Any best practice on where that logic would reside, I could put it in the main model A, inside the Collection B, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

JS Bin link:

http://jsbin.com/ejohom/1/edit

I only explored a different way to structure your Model and Collection.  I created a testData structure which would represent how you are loading this data at init time.

Also you will see a continent finder function in the collection.